# Browser-based web testing

Tags: testing

I need suggestion on a software being able to run web page tests in a very graphical way, like "Click the button with text 'Hello' and you should be redirect on this page' or "Fill this form with this data, go to this page and check if the number of items is 5".

I'm aware of some BDD tools for ruby and scriptable frameworks like mechanize for perl or SimpleTest for PHP, but I'm specifically looking for something more UI oriented, working well with JS and ignoring everything happening on the server side, just interacting with the pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is what we use. It provides programmatic testing. like you load the page, click on specific button, select particular check box ..

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)
- [WebTest](http://webtest.canoo.com/webtest/manual/WebTestHome.html)
- WatiX - X being n, r, j, depending on the language.

Answer (score 0):

[iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) is another option.